# How can mybatis collection retain duplicate data?

Tags: java, mybatis

```
    <collection property="studentName" ofType="java.lang.String">
        <result column="student_name"/>
    </collection>
    <collection property="studentClass" ofType="java.lang.String">
        <result column="student_class"/>
    </collection>
    <collection property="studentGrade" ofType="java.lang.String">
        <result column="student_grade"/>
    </collection>
```

The above is my mapping, but in this way, only one of the same results will be retained. How can I make it contain duplicate data?

The result is like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMu8O.png)

But the result I want is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXXqW.png)

That is to say, the data is the same and the results are retained, what should I do, thank you!